# using localhost MySql from online Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a Codeigniter project on a machine and it runs as public access. However the MySql database it uses is accessible only through localhost. When I run the application, I get

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

I follwed the instructions mentioned [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/207916/) but I am still getting the same error

```
Try

1. print_r($params) and print_r($active_record);

2. if the $params are still correct then simplify $active_record

3. echo mysql_error();

4. $db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = true/false

5. $db[‘default’][‘stricton’] = true/false;
```

[edited]

I have set the parameters as

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql12.freehostia.com';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'myDB';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = false;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = false;
```

Comment: Either your mysql is not running or your connection parameters are not correct. The link you are following is rubbish. Debugging false will supperss the error, not solve it.

Comment: and you are hosting your files on? same server?

Comment: `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';` try that.